# Run macro based on response in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Would it be possible for me to write a macro where - command button will check a table (similar to the one below) for Yes responses within Column A

For example

Column A
Responses

- Yes
- No
- NA
- Yes
- Yes

Column B
Corresponding Tab name

- Tab - 001
- Tab - 002
- Tab - 003
- Tab - 004
- Tab - 005

If the response is "Yes" then it should - run 'CopysheetandRename' and name the tab according to the Tab name in Column B - macro below
I understand I'd have to remove the input box and somehow replace it with the tan name in Column B (ie 'Tab - 001') in the looping function. However I'm not sure how this could be done.

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
Dim newName As String

On Error Resume Next
newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    Range("$D$3").Value = newName
End If

Dim n As Name
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
n.Visible = True
Next n

Dim numrow
numrow = Range("F16").Value

If IsNumeric(numrow) Then

For i = 1 To numrow

Call INRW

Next i

End If

End Sub'
```

Ultimately what I'm attempting to achieve is a command button that will help me generate Tab - 001,Tab - 004,Tab - 005 through a command button and the use of the existing macro 'Copysheetandrename'

Hope it makes sense and sorry about the long question

Edit:

I've uploaded the original xlsm in the google drive link below:
[Link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fpgqlyDN72OC6S9NOh_MTh5Ur4ZKWz46
In the file the 'Responses' are in Column O and Corresponding tab name is in Column C. The button for 'Copysheetandrename' is located in the 'Template' tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Replace with your Command Button name
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

With Me
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = "Yes" Then Call CopySheetAndRename(.Cells(i, 2).Value2)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

For this to work you will need to change your existing procedure like this:

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename(Optional newName As String = "")

On Error Resume Next
If newName = "" Then newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    ActiveSheet.Range("$D$3").Value = newName
End If

Dim n As Name
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    n.Visible = True
Next n

Dim numrow
numrow = Range("F16").Value

If IsNumeric(numrow) Then

For i = 1 To numrow
    Call INRW
Next i

End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updated to fit OPs dataset:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Replace with your Command Button name
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Me
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 15).Value2 = "Yes" Then Call CopySheetAndRename(.Cells(i, 3).Value2)
        Next i
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: So using actual data if the Yes/No responses were in Column O and Tab names were in Column C, I'd change the code as below? 

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Replace with your Command Button name
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 15).Value2 = "Yes" Then CopySheetAndRename (.Cells(i, 3).Value2)
    Next i
End With

End Sub`

Comment: Almost right, you need to change `lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`to `lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`. I edited my answer to include this version as well

Comment: Try to avoid ActiveSheet.

Comment: @TommyLi Please consider marking the question as answered if your problem is solved.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to share the file here? It's a bit hard explaining through text what I'm trying to achieve without referring to the file

Comment: I've been getting the error 'compile error - wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'

Would it be because 'Copysheetandrename' is not on the same tab?

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpgqlyDN72OC6S9NOh_MTh5Ur4ZKWz46/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your workbook is password protected so I can't access it. Try to put a `Call` statement in front of `CopySheetAndRename`, like this: `Then Call CopySheetAndRename(.Cells(i, 3).Value2)`. Also make sure your CommandButton code is in the VBA code for the sheet the button is on. I just tried it on some sample data and it worked as intended.

Comment: @TommyLi I also updated the code above to include a direct reference to the worksheet `Me` inside `CommandButton1_Click` instead of `ActiveSheet`.